# slime-lookup-definition not working with sbcl

Tags: emacs

One of the nicer things of programming with Common Lisp and the combination of Emacs / Slime is, that you can jump quickly to the source of builtin or your own functions with

<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

I can't get this to work however, for sbcl's builtin functions. I have the package `sbcl-source` installed, but as you can see from this screenshot:
[image]

If I choose the definition I want to visit (the buffer to the right) it only opens a empty buffer with the (correct) filename I wanted to see.

How can I get the correct behaviour?

Edit: I had the exact same problem with 13.04/12.10. However, when using Arch Linux, this works flawlessly.

Edit: According to [this post](http://xach.livejournal.com/300290.html#) I added the sbcl-source path to my sbclrc. slime-xref is pointing to the correct file, but when I try to visit the desired function, I still only get an empty buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

You have to add the following line to your `.sbclrc` :

```
(sb-ext:set-sbcl-source-location "/usr/share/sbcl-source/")
```

Then, restart slime, and jump happily from definition to definition and back again.